# Error al eliminar dato en phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy tratando de eliminar un dato en una tabla en phpmyadmin, cuando entro a la tabla y le doy borrar, no borra el dato. Si lo intento
borrar como una consulta desde la consola me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

1054 la columna en where clause es desconocida

Esto es lo que ejecuto:

```
DELETE FROM `encabezadocotizacion` WHERE `encabezadocotizacion`.`idCotizacion` = COQ-69318
```

Comment: Te hacen falta comillas despues del `=`

Answer (score 1):

la sentencia DELETE es asi:

```
DELETE FROM encabezadocotizacion WHERE idCotizacion='COQ-69318'
```

tambien se puede usar asi:

```
DELETE FROM encabezadocotizacion WHERE encabezadocotizacion.idCotizacion='COQ-69318'
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el problema es que el elemento del `WHERE` esta separado por culpa de las comillas. Prueba con:

```
DELETE FROM encabezadocotizacion WHERE encabezadocotizacion.idCotizacion = 'COQ-69318'
```

Esta otra sentencia también debería funcionar:

```
DELETE FROM encabezadocotizacion WHERE idCotizacion = 'COQ-69318'
```